# Trouble understanding solution to ProjectEuler 19

Tags: c++

I found this solution to problem 19 on ProjectEuler on GitHub which I would really like to understand. I was curious on how to solve the problem but didn't really know how to attack it and then stumbled upon this solution. The problem however, is the following:

[image]

And I found the following solution:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count = 0, days_in_month, days_passed = 2;

for(int i = 1901; i <= 2000; i++){
    for(lnt j = 1; j <= 12; j++){
        if(j == 4 || j == 6 || j == 9 || j == 11)
            days_in_month = 30;
        else if(j == 2){
            if(i % 400 == 0 || (i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0))
                days_in_month = 29;
            else
                days_in_month = 28;
        }else
            days_in_month = 31;

    //Here's where I start to get a little fuzzy
        if(days_passed % 7 == 0)
            count++;
        days_passed += days_in_month;
    }
}
cout << count << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I'm not entirely certain what's happening after the 'if(days_passed % 7 == 0)'-line. I get that the modulo-division by 7 is to check for sundays, and if it is a sunday 'count' gets added by one. What I don't get is the 'days_passed += days_in_month'-line. That would mean that days_passed gets the value 33 for the second day in january, right? Why is that?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: _"I had to screenshot the description of the problem and my code and upload the pictures since the editor didn't accept my writing for whatever reason"_ Regarding this read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) first please.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `days_passed` as *the number of days that have passed since the first Sunday*.  Each iteration advances this to the start of the next month by adding the number of days in the current month to that value.  And, as you say, anytime that value is a multiple of 7, the first day of that month is a Sunday.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I get your idea, I think; Since you start counting on the first sunday, every seventh day after that will be a sunday no matter what date it is. But what I'm a little unsure of is, on which day does 'days_passed' start counting on? It's initialised with a value of 2, but the first sunday in 1905 was on the 5th. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Assuming you mean 1900 and not 1905, then on Jan 1, 1900, 2 days will have passed since the last Sunday of 1899.

Comment: Oh, yes! I meant 1900. But now that I look, isn't it one day? Dec 31, 1899 was on a sunday, then the next day is Jan 1, 1900. A monday. Shouldn't days_passed be set to 1?